# Selecting distinct rows from datatable in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using linq query to select 2 distinct columns id and name from a datatable. I've the code below but it's throwing error specific cast is invalid.

```
sdatatable = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>    
             ("TableName") == "header").CopyToDataTable();

rptcourse.DataSource = sdatatable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
        {
            locationid = row.Field<string>("locationID"),
            locationname = row.Field<string>("locationname")
        }).Distinct();
```

Any suggestions could help.

Comment: what is the type of sdatatable?

Comment: It's a datatable.

Comment: Please show the *exact* exception message. We can't help you if we don't see the types that are in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code returns an `IEnumerble<T>` while the `DataSource` is probably expecting a `List<T>`. Add a `ToList()` after the `Distinct()`:

```
rptcourse.DataSource = sdatatable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
        {
            locationid = Convert.ToInt32(row["locationid"]),
            locationname = row.Field<string>("locationname")
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

You can also just join the two queries this way:

```
rptcourse.DataSource  = ds.Tables[0].Where(x => x.Field<string>("TableName") == "header")
            .Select(row => new
            {
                locationid =  Convert.ToInt32(row["locationid"])
                locationname = row.Field<string>("locationname")
            })
            .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I tried two of your solutions but still get the same error.

Comment: @BVidhya - at what point are you getting the exception? What does it say - which is the invalid cast?

Comment: On the attribute locationid and locationname it throws error specific cast is not valid. I changed locationid field type to int. but still throws error

Comment: @BVidhya - what are the type of the columns?

Comment: Locationid - int, locationname - varchar

Comment: @BVidhya - is it a nullable int in any chance?

Comment: The datatset data that I've retrieved is the result of 3 select statements using union. In this case locationid can hold null.

Comment: no luck still the same error. I applied your changes but still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122426/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-b-vidhya).